# PDF dynamic content - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, pdf, dynamic, itext, pdfbox

Is it possible to insert dynamic (remote) content in a pdf?
I know there are many ways & libraries to generate pdf dynamically. I have a brief idea about iText/PDFBox. We also have ACROForms and javascript action within forms.

Is it possible to fetch remote content [Eg: Today's deals] when the pdf document is opened every time?

If Yes, please provide any pointers to the technique/tools available (preferably Java based & free/open-source)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only if you use JavaScript in your PDF *and* the users have a viewer that supports JavaScript in PDF. PDF itself is static.

Comment: @user3150983: I don't know of any free PDF viewer that supports JavaScript the way AR does; it's certainly a can of worms securitywise.